# Why is the data inside a query result not typed, when extracted?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql

I have a graphQL query which I run in a React component.

```
const { loading, error, data, refetch }: ExampleQueryHookResult = useExampleQuery(
    {
      variables: { clientId: graphQlClientId },
    },
  );
```

And then get the data by unpacking it

```
const exampleData = data?.example?.first;
```

At that point my ID tells me that the type of exampleData is 'any'.
I would have expected to get properly typed data, as GraphQL has all it needs to do so, right?
What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What does `ExampleQueryHookResult` look like?

Comment: Just realized that for my colleagues it is typed so likely a local problem with my VSCode settings.